# Detecting IE version not considering compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-detection

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to detect what version of IE you are using, and not your document-mode. It can be server or client-code (doesn't matter), I just need to know what version of IE the user has installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be detected in both, by examining the User-Agent string. Note that browsers can spoof their UA string, but this is rarer now than in the past. See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(VS.85).aspx) for older UA strings.

Note also that IE8 sends a different UA string in Compatibility mode and in Standards mode (see [this](http://www.user-agents.org/cgi-bin/csv2html.pl?data=allagents.csv&template=detail.html&match=%5Cbid_moz_080209_2%5Cb) and [this](http://www.user-agents.org/cgi-bin/csv2html.pl?data=allagents.csv&template=detail.html&match=%5Cbid_moz_080209_3%5Cb) - both are IE8, although the former says `MSIE 7.0`).

See [this](http://www.user-agents.org/index.shtml?moz) for a long list of UA strings - note that you should be looking for a pattern, not exact match, as installed software will modify the UA string.

IE9 has some new UA string thing - [see the IEBlog for details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx).

To summarize (and borrow from [@EricLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126229/ericlaw-msft)'s comment):

- no Trident in UA string - check the `MSIE [0-9].0` string for version
- Trident/4.0 - IE 8, version in `MSIE` is not relevant
- Trident/5.0 - IE 9

Comment: @Alxandr: I think IEBlog is quite clear here: "Version token is incremented from ‘MSIE 8.0’ to ‘MSIE 9.0’. 
Trident token is incremented from ‘Trident/4.0’ to ‘Trident/5.0’." (added link to IEBlog into answer) So: no Trident - whatever version `MSIE \d.0` is. Trident 4.0 - MSIE8. Trident 5.0 - MSIE 9.

Comment: Look for the Trident token. "Trident/5.0"== IE9. "Trident/4.0" == IE8.