# How to redirect browser to an upgrade page if user is using ie8 or lower

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript redirect for Internet Explorer browser version user agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407182/javascript-redirect-for-internet-explorer-browser-version-user-agent)
>   [Detect IE version in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript)

What is the best practice if I do not want to allow any users to use the site unless they have ie9 or higher, or firefox/chrome/safari.  ie7 and ie8 should not work and it should redirect to a notification page that tells the user to upgrade his or her browser.  Is this even the best practice for this situation?  If so, how would the code look in javascript.

Comment: This has been asked many many times, please search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539280/detecting-ie-version-not-considering-compatibility-mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407182/javascript-redirect-for-internet-explorer-browser-version-user-agent